# In xul, how to retrieve an environment variable?

Tags: javascript, linux, environment-variables, xul, xulrunner

I have an environment called `$REP`, how can I access the value of this variable using Xulrunner in a Linux environment?

**--udpate**

attempting with [nslEnvironment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEnvironment):

```
var env = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
dump("bash=" + env.exists("BASH") + '\n');
dump("bash=" + env.exists("$BASH") + '\n');
```

the output was:

```
bash=false
bash=false
```

as you imagine, it should output "/bin/bash" as it does in the terminal. I also tried using `get` to see if it was just the `exists` method wrong, but it returned empty.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [nsIEnvironment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEnvironment) to read (and set) environment variables.

Comment: `BASH` isn't an environment variable, it's a shell variable. (Compare the output of `set` and `env`.)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Setting an environment variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768477/setting-an-environment-variable-in-javascript/938081#938081) (which you happened to edit, randomly!).

I very much doubt you'll be able to read these variables from a browser environment though.

edit:

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var oSysEnv = oShell.Environment("SYSTEM");
WScript.Echo (oSysEnv("PATH"));
```

perhaps?

Comment: if you see the source of what I edited, you'll se that I removed the < pre > and add the code formating, so it gets the sintax hightlight.. ;)
Also, as you see, I already saw that question and the answers, but there's nothing about how to read. Thanks for the second line of your answer, maybe it's not possible..

Comment: I didn't know about that, I'm reasonably new to this :o.

Comment: It throws "WScript not defined". Actually, I didn't understand fully this script. I imagine I'm just supposed to change the "PATH" value with my variable's name, I tried the system variable "BASH", but the problem occurred on the first line with WScript.

Comment: This is only available in Windows in Internet Explorer (or anything that uses JScript).